# A am trying to get the value of an input in nodejs with body-parser, it shows no errors in the code but the value returns empty

Tags: node.js, body-parser

i have this project where i use NodeJS and body-parser to get the value of an input from a ejs page, and even if it shows no errors in the code the value returns empty.

i have tried to use app.use
(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
and
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
and
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
and 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
and the value returns either empty {} of undefined when i console.log it

```
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

var friends = ["Tony", "Alex", "Misu", "Marius"];

app.get("/", (req,res) => {
    res.render("home");
});

app.post("/addfriend", (req, res) =>{
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send("You have reached the post route!");
});

app.get("/friends", (req, res) => {
    res.render("friends", {friends: friends});
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("SERVER ONLINE");
});
```

Comment: Include what your request looks like.  Chances are you probably want `bodyParser.json()`.  Also, for `GET` `/friends`, you reference an undeclared variable `friends`.  You probably want to do something like `req.body.friends`.

Comment: thank you...sorted out.....i put the name attribute to the wrong input, that`s why i was getting empty value. friends is not a variable, is a ref to friends.ejs. This line  ```app.set("view engine", "ejs");``` tells the app to look just for friends without the extension in the view folder.